# GNU Parallel -- How to understand "block-size" setting, and guess what to set it to?

Tags: grep, gnu-parallel

How do I set the block-size parameter when running grep using GNU parallel on a single machine with multiple cores, based on the "large_file" filesize, "small_file" filesize and machine I'm using to get the fastest performance possible (or please correct me if there is something else that im missing here)? What are the performance issues/speed bottlenecks I'll run into when setting it too high or too low? I understand *what* block-size does, in that it blocks out the large_file in chunks, and sends those chunks to each job, but I'm still missing the potential for how and why that would impact speed of execution.

The command in question:

```
parallel --pipepart --block 100M --jobs 10 -a large_file.csv grep -f small_file.csv
```

where large_file.csv has in it:

```
123456    1
234567    2
345667    22
```

and 
where small_file.csv has in it:

```
    1$
    2$
```

and so on...

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest review Amdahl’s Law here: https://www.cs.uky.edu/~jzhang/CS621/chapter7.pdf .In this problem it is necessary to take into account that the reading from hard disk is not parallel, because only one thread can read at a time.

Comment: Thanks! I reviewed it -- nice material, thank you for sending it my way. I understand that I'm limited by the inherently serial reading from harddisk, but the question stemmed from the following observation which led me to believe that perhaps other parameters could help: I got wildly different run times from one run to the next using similarly sized small_files and large_files. I was hoping block_size was one lever that could help, but am not sure...

Comment: Keep in mind that time variations may be due to the variations in resources that the operating system currently has. For a more "pure" test, close all the programs you can, or even perform your test in Linux kernel mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parallel --pipepart --block -1 --jobs 10 -a large_file.csv grep -f small_file.csv
```

`--block -1` will split large_file.csv into one block per jobslot (here 10 chunks). The splitting will be done on the fly, so it will not be read into RAM to do the splitting.

Splitting into n evenly sized blocks (where n = number of jobs to run in parallel) often makes sense if the time spent per line is roughly the same. If it varies a lot (say, some lines take 100 times longer to process than others), then it may make more sense to chop into more bits. E.g. `--block -10` will split into 10 times as many blocks as `--block -1`.

The optimal value can seldom be guessed in advance, because it may also depend on how fast your disk is. So try different values and identify where the bottleneck is. It is typically one of disk I/O, CPU, RAM, command startup time.

Comment: Does this setting (-1) assume that the available RAM exceeds the size of large_file.csv?

Comment: Opposite `--pipe` `--pipepart` does not cache in RAM and is much faster. It only works on files, though.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry one last follow up, if you dont mind: what makes --block -1 the best setting? Trying to understand a (perhaps obvious to others) concept here. I can hazard a guess: if you split it up smaller, you're essentially making a queue of file-size/(block-size) elements -- is this a correct understanding?